# i receive data type Uint8Array from port serial how can i transfer to decimal value [ web serial port ]

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

**I get weight from rocking**

exemple data :

```
Uint8Array(6) [118, 118, 246, 86, 15, 0]
0: 118
1: 118
2: 246
3: 86
4: 15
5: 0
buffer: (...)
byteLength: (...)
byteOffset: (...)
length: (...)
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): (...)
__proto__: TypedArray
```

**weight is decimal but i receive data type Uint8Array how I transform it to decimal
thanks**

```
var port;
var buffy = new ArrayBuffer(1);
var writer;
buffy[0] = 10;
const portstart = async function() {
    const requestOptions = {
        // Filter on devices with the Arduino USB vendor ID.
        //filters: [{ vendorId: 0x2341 }],
    };
    // Request an Arduino from the user.
    port = await navigator.serial.requestPort(requestOptions);
    // Open and begin reading.
    await port.open({
        baudRate: 9600
    });
    //const reader = port.in.getReader();
    //  const reader = port.readable.getReader();
    //writer = port.writable.getWriter();
    //const writer = port.writable.getWriter();
    //writer.write(buffy);

    while (port.readable) {
        const reader = port.readable.getReader();

        //  const textDecoder = new TextDecoderStream();
        //const readableStreamClosed = port.readable.pipeTo(textDecoder.writable);
        //const reader = textDecoder.readable.getReader();

        try {
            while (true) {
                const {
                    value,
                    done
                } = await reader.read();
                if (done) {
                    // Allow the serial port to be closed later.
                    reader.releaseLock();
                    break;
                }
                if (value) {
                    const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
                    console.log(decoder.decode(value));
                    console.log(value);
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            // TODO: Handle non-fatal read error.
        }
    }

} // end of function
```

Comment: You mean, how to change `const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8"); console.log(decoder.decode(value));` to what output?

Comment: console.log(decoder.decode(value)); return incoding value like ����

Comment: What actual input and expected output?

Comment: expected output is simple integer  value

Comment: scales send weight  to monitor serial port

Comment: Please share actual examples

Comment: that was all code used to get data from serial port

Comment: code is fine but result is Uint8Array how can transfert to integer value thanks